# What does "subrange" mean in the HTTP spec?

Tags: http, caching, etag

See, for example, [§13.3.3](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.3) and [§13.3.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec13.html#sec13.3.4).

It doesn't seem to me that this could be related to "media range" ([§14.1](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.1), e.g. `Accept: text/*`), nor "language range" ([§14.4](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.4), e.g. `Accept-Language: da, en-gb;q=0.8, en;q=0.7`).

Maybe it's the "accept range" ([§14.5](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec14.html#sec14.5)), which puts byte limitations on a response?  If that's true, how do `ETag`s relate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure it's for range retrieval requests, i.e. requesting part of a document (resuming a file download, for example).

> 14.35.2 Range Retrieval Requests
>
> HTTP retrieval requests using
>   conditional or unconditional GET
>   methods MAY request one or more
>   sub-ranges of the entity, instead of
>   the entire entity, using the Range
>   request header, which applies to
>   the entity returned as the result of
>   the request:

If the `ETag` is weak (starts with `W/`) then it can't be used for a range retrieval - only strong validators can be used for that or the client may end up with an inconsistent file.